# Change custom ringtone of a phone number is not change on some Nougat device (LG - K10, OS -7.0)

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want to change ringtone of given phone number programmatically.
I have facing below mention issues.

**1. Ringtone is not change on some Nougat device (LG k10, Samsung).**
**2. It is working fine below the Nougat device.**

I am using below mention code to change the ringtone of phone number.

```
  private fun funChangeRingtone(number: String) {
        try {
            // The Uri used to look up a contact by phone number
            val lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, number)
            // The columns used for `Contacts.getLookupUri`
            val projection = arrayOf<String>(Contacts._ID, Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY)
            // Build your Cursor
            val data = contentResolver.query(lookupUri, projection, null, null, null)
            data!!.moveToFirst()
            try {
                // Get the contact lookup Uri
                val contactId = data.getLong(0)
                val lookupKey = data.getString(1)
                val contactUri = Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey) ?: // Invalid arguments
                        return


                val file = File(/*storage + "/AudioRecorder",*/ audio /*+ ".mp3"*/)
                file.setReadable(true, false);
                var value: Uri
               /* if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    value = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, null, file);
                    grantUriPermission("com.example", value, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                } else {*/
                value = Uri.fromFile(file)/*.toString()*/
//                }


                // Apply the custom ringtone
                val values = ContentValues()

                values.put(Contacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, value.toString())
                var permission = false;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    permission = Settings.System.canWrite(this)
                } else {
                    permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                }
                if (permission) {
                    val update = contentResolver.update(contactUri, values, null, null)
                    Log.d("update", update.toString())                  




                }
            } finally {
                // Don't forget to close your Cursor
                data.close()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```